# Testing subgroups for significance in cox regression - how to format data

Tags: r, regression, anova

I want to test if it is worth splitting a variable into subgroups. The research question that I have is: *does it adds anything to the prognosis knowing if the cancer is located on the forearm or if arm is sufficient?*

My plan is to use the `rms`-package and test models with `anova()`. I initially thought that I would be able to get away with a simple `x1 + x1:x2` but I don't think the `model.matrix` looks quite right. Here's an illustration of what I mean:

```
library(magrittr)
n <- 12
test_data <- data.frame(
  x1 = factor(rep(c(1, 2),
                  each = n/2),
              labels = c("a", "b")),
  x2 = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = n/4),
             rep(LETTERS[3:4], each = n/4))
)

# Now we add some code for manually generating the interaction variables
test_data %<>% 
  within({
    is_a_and_x2 <- x2
    is_a_and_x2[x1 != "a"] <- LETTERS[1]
    is_b_and_x2 <- x2 
    is_b_and_x2[x1 == "a"] <- LETTERS[3]
    is_a_and_x2 <- factor(is_a_and_x2)
    is_b_and_x2 <- factor(is_b_and_x2)
  })
```

The data looks as following:

```
| x1 | x2 | is_b_and_x2 | is_a_and_x2 |
|----+----+-------------+-------------|
| a  | A  | C           | A           |
| a  | A  | C           | A           |
| a  | A  | C           | A           |
| a  | B  | C           | B           |
| a  | B  | C           | B           |
| a  | B  | C           | B           |
| b  | C  | C           | A           |
| b  | C  | C           | A           |
| b  | C  | C           | A           |
| b  | D  | D           | A           |
| b  | D  | D           | A           |
| b  | D  | D           | A           |
```

Now if we do a simple `model.matrix`:

```
model.matrix( ~ x1 + is_a_and_x2 + is_b_and_x2, data = test_data)
```

We get the expected:

```
|================================================== 
| (Intercept) | x1b | is_a_and_x2B | is_b_and_x2D 
| 1           | 0   | 0            | 0            
| 1           | 0   | 0            | 0            
| 1           | 0   | 0            | 0            
| 1           | 0   | 1            | 0            
| 1           | 0   | 1            | 0            
| 1           | 0   | 1            | 0            
| 1           | 1   | 0            | 0            
| 1           | 1   | 0            | 0            
| 1           | 1   | 0            | 0            
| 1           | 1   | 0            | 1            
| 1           | 1   | 0            | 1            
| 1           | 1   | 0            | 1            
|==================================================
```

Now this looks like a reasonable design matrix but I can't recreate it using a simple formula:

```
model.matrix( ~ x1 + x1 : x2, data = test_data)
```

Gives:

```
|================================================================================ 
| (Intercept) | x1b | x1a:x2B | x1b:x2B | x1a:x2C | x1b:x2C | x1a:x2D | x1b:x2D 
| 1           | 0   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       
|================================================================================
```

Using some aggressive cleaning we get:

```
model.matrix( ~ x1 + x1 : x2, data = test_data) %>% 
  t %>% 
  .[!duplicated(.),] %>% 
  t

|============================================================ 
| (Intercept) | x1b | x1a:x2B | x1b:x2B | x1b:x2C | x1b:x2D 
| 1           | 0   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 0   | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       
| 1           | 1   | 0       | 0       | 0       | 1       
|============================================================
```

**My question: Is there a more convenient method than the hand-made variables or should I use a different approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some `dplyr` and a little hacking I think I have a solution that works:

```
library(magrittr)
n <- 12
test_data <- data.frame(
  x1 = factor(rep(c(1, 2),
                  each = n/2),
              labels = c("a", "b")),
  x2 = c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = n/4),
         rep(LETTERS[3:4], each = n/4))
)

library(dplyr)
test_data %>% 
  select(x1, x2) %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  arrange(x1, desc(n)) %>% 
  group_by(x1) %>% 
  do({
    x1_name <- as.character(.$x1[1])
        test_data[[x1_name]] <<-
          test_data$x2
    test_data[[x1_name]] <<- 
      relevel(test_data[[x1_name]], ref = as.character(.$x2[1]))
        test_data[[x1_name]][test_data$x1 != x1_name] <<-
      .$x2[1]
    test_data[[x1_name]] <<- factor(test_data[[x1_name]])
    .
  })

model.matrix( ~ x1 + a + b, data = test_data) %>% 
  knitr::kable()
```

Produces the following output:

```
| (Intercept)| x1b| aB| bD|
|-----------:|---:|--:|--:|
|           1|   0|  0|  0|
|           1|   0|  0|  0|
|           1|   0|  0|  0|
|           1|   0|  1|  0|
|           1|   0|  1|  0|
|           1|   0|  1|  0|
|           1|   1|  0|  0|
|           1|   1|  0|  0|
|           1|   1|  0|  0|
|           1|   1|  0|  1|
|           1|   1|  0|  1|
|           1|   1|  0|  1|
```

Important to note is the `<<-` - this is necessary as we otherwise don't reach the scope of the non-dplyr environment, i.e. the setting of `test_data` with a simple `<-` would not affect the test_data.